# I don't know what my custom adapter is not working in my custom listview

Tags: android

I don't know if I am defining my custom adapter correctly...what part did I implement wrong? nothing is showing up. Also, can somebody tell me a good tutorial where I can learn about customizing baseAdapters?

I defined my custom adapter getView part as follow:

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {  
    //The part 
    itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,arg2,false);
    return itemView;
```

I think I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell where you are doing wrong, as there is not much code you have posted. If you want some good tutorials you can find them [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).